# What is the smallest Keras regression neural network model will give me a perfect fit on cars data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression

I am looking  [this cars dataset](https://github.com/MGCodesandStats/datasets/blob/master/cars.csv). I build and train a regression model with this code, adapted from [this article](https://datascienceplus.com/keras-regression-based-neural-networks/) and [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression).  I am using all of the training data (no train/test split):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
dataset=np.loadtxt("cars.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
x=dataset[:,0:5]
y=dataset[:,5]
y=np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler()
print(scaler_x.fit(x))
xscale=scaler_x.transform(x)
print(scaler_y.fit(y))
yscale=scaler_y.transform(y)
model = Sequential([
    Dense(2048, activation='relu', input_dim=5),
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
  ])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(xscale, yscale, epochs=1000, batch_size=577,  verbose=1, validation_split=0)
Xnew= scaler_x.transform(Xnew)
ynew= model.predict(Xnew)
ynew = scaler_y.inverse_transform(ynew) 
Znew = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_train)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.scatter(Znew,ynew);
```

After 1000 epochs this model will closely but not exactly fit the input training data:

[image]

This model has 2,635,777 trainable parameters (the data itself has only 5,778 numbers in it).

What is the smallest Keras regression model (in terms of total number of trainable parameters) that will train up to an almost perfect fit on this data (which has 5 input parameters, 1 output parameters, and 963 samples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Grogan here - I'm the original author of this data and example, so hope I can assist you.

You mention that you have not invoked a validation split in your data. May I ask if there a reason for this? The purpose of splitting into training and validation is for the model to take feedback from the validation parameters and then update the forecasts accordingly.

It has been quite a while since I've looked at this example, but here is an example of a training/validation split, and the training and validation loss appears to bottom out after 20 epochs - so 1000 is not strictly required. The original tutorial I wrote used 150 epochs in the example.

x and y are split as follows:

```
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(xscale, yscale, random_state=0)
```

I then ran the model using your configurations:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(2048, activation='relu', input_dim=5),
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
  ])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=577,  verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Here is the training and validation loss graph:

[image: graph]

> > > What is the smallest Keras regression model (in terms of total number of trainable parameters) that will train up to an almost perfect fit on this data (which has 5 input parameters, 1 output parameters, and 963 samples)?

When you say "smallest Keras regression model", you appear to be referring to the one that uses the least number of features in order to achieve the same (or better accuracy). One way this could be determined is using a feature selection tool such as the **ExtraTreesClassifier**, where each feature is ranked in terms of its importance (the higher the number, the more important).

Given the features age, gender, miles, debt, and income, here are the results:

```
In:

from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(x, y)
print(model.feature_importances_)

Out: [0.23371284 0.01554055 0.23787049 0.25267784 0.26019827]
```

With the exception of gender, the other features are ranked similarly in terms of importance.

In this regard, let us run the model again, but this time without the gender variable.

Here is the model (only change is that input_dim = 4), and here is the new training and validation loss:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(2048, activation='relu', input_dim=4),
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
  ])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=577,  verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

[image: graph2]

The hidden layers in your example look quite large, so let's try and simplify this down a bit:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(12, activation='relu', input_dim=4),
    Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='linear')
  ])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=577,  verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Now when the model is trained again, here is the new training and validation loss:

[image: graph3]

We now see that it takes roughly 50 epochs instead of 20 to get a similar training and validation loss. In this regard, there seems to be a tradeoff between the size of the hidden layers, and the number of epochs used to train the model.

Generally speaking, the model required 4 input parameters and a lot less than 1000 epochs to generate a good fit.

One caveat - the true test as to whether the data will fit "perfectly" is to test the predictions against unseen data. For instance, we have used training and validation data to build the model. A portion of this data should be kept entirely separate, and then compared with the model predictions to ensure accuracy - this is the **litmus test** as to whether the model is truly working - and I would recommend this as a next step to ensure that your model is robust.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: I am working on a rheumatoid arthritis X-ray reading challenge: https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn20545111/wiki/594083.  Input is an image and output is a score like 0,1,2,3,4,5.  However the training data is missing examples for 3,4.  So I need a regression model.  I've never done regression in a neural net before.  My question is really about the expressive power of the model.  Because I don't know regression in neural nets I am looking for the most compact/clever layer architecture to do regression learning.   Note: You are welcome to join the challenge!

Comment: Sounds very interesting, would be great to hear more. My contact details are included in my profile page - feel free to reach out.

Comment: You can register for the challenge on Synapse site from above link.  I don't run the challenge, I am a solver, but as a solver I welcome additional competition.  At the moment I think we are a bit stuck because the docs didn't give us enough training data.